# Batch script to read the last word of a sentence

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to get last word from a sentence or file path

I tried solutions from other articles and forums but can't seem to figure it out. here is what I have so far

```
@echo off
set a="C:\Some\Random\File\Path.txt"
echo %a%
set b=%a:\= %
echo %b%
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%b%) do @echo %%a %%b %%c
pause
```

All I need is the last word of what ever file path I put in %a%

Comment: Parameter Extensions might help you here. `%%~na` will Expand `%%a` to a file Name without file extension or path. More info here: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html

Comment: See the `shift` command. Loop until `%2` empty. Then `%1` will contain the last word.

Comment: @catcat why do that if you can simply use variable references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer specifically on your question:

```
@echo off
set "a=C:\Some\Random\File\Path.txt"
for %%i in (%a%) do echo %%~nxi
pause
```

Also see how I used the double quotes on the `set`ting of the variable, This allows us to get rid of any wanted whitespace after the value, and also if we add the quotes after the equal, they become part of the value, which is not what we really want.

To understand the variable references, for from cmdline `for /?` I suggest you also see `set /?`

Additionally, based on your comment, if you want to set it as a viarble, simply do it :)

```
@echo off
set "a=C:\Some\Random\File\Path.txt"
for %%i in (%a%) do set variablename=%%~nxi
echo %variablename%
pause
```

Comment: Your answer is great although it does cut off the file extension. Also do you think you could assign the output to a variable afterward?

Comment: @ExpiredRamen172 But that was your requirement as per the last line,  but I changed it now, you simply require an x for extention from `%%~ni` to `%%~nxi` please have a look again.

Answer (score 1):

While Gerhards solution **IS** preferable (for path), your approach wasn't that bad.

You just have to use a simple for,
so it iterates over the space seperated elements which therefor have to be unquoted.

Repeatedly setting the same variable will have the last value/word persisting.

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\01\18\SO_54246604.cmd
@echo off
set "a=C:\Some\Random\File\Path.txt"
echo %a%
for  %%a in (%a:\= %) do Set "b=%%a"
echo %b%
pause
```

---

```
> SO_54246604.cmd
C:\Some\Random\File\Path.txt
Path.txt
```

Comment: Gerhard's solution is only preferable, for file paths. The question specifically mentions sentences or file paths, which means that your answer is preferable as it is more likely to achieve both.

Comment: @Compo I answered not on what the OP `echo`'d in his example as it seems he was doing that to attempt finding which variable contains the filename but I answered rather on what the last line states _"All I need is the last word of what ever file path I put in %a%"_

Comment: @Gerhard, I'm aware that you've answered it based on the last line, I however felt that the title and first line took precedence, hence my comment above. I'm not criticising your answer, I just felt that this one covered both scenarios and therefore the question better.